# How to handle parameters in shortcode function

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I'm doing my first shortcode for WordPress. The function that I'm doing will return different translation of a string depending on the parameter `se` for swedish or `en` for english. So I'm going to use a simple `if statement` or a `switch statement`, but which of the two option below are the best and what's the difference between them? Should I use `$a` or `language` to check the in parameter? The default value is `se` for swedish.

```
$a = shortcode_atts( array(
'language' => 'se',
), $atts );
```

or

```
extract(shortcode_atts(array("language"=>"se"),$atts));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$a['language']` will give you the value of the language key.

Or a full example:

```
// [my_shortcode language="value"]
function my_shortcode_function( $atts ) {
    $a = shortcode_atts( array(
        'language' => 'se',
    ), $atts );

    if ( $a['language'] == 'en' ) {
        $language = 'Hello';
    } elseif ( $a['language'] == 'se' ) {
        $language = 'Hej';
    } else {
        $language = 'Incorrect language specified';
    }

    return $language;
}
add_shortcode( 'my_shortcode', 'my_shortcode_function' );
```

Comment: Nice, but I was was more looking for two options like if parameter is 'se' the the return should be a string in swedish or if the parameter is 'en' the return should be a string in english

Comment: Then write a conditional...in place of the `return` above

Comment: `if ( $a['language'] == 'en' ) { //do something } elseif ( $a['language'] == 'se' ) { //do something else } else { // return }`

Comment: OK, like this then: if ( $a['language'] == 'en' ) { $language = "Hello"; } elseif ( $a['language'] == 'se' ) { $language = "Hej"; } else { // $language = "A default value"; } return $language;

Comment: Perhaps an option also if the is an empty parameter that will return a default value? Like elseif ( $a['language'] == '' ) { $language = "Tag" } Tag = hello in german

Comment: Hmmm, just looking at the code, if there is a default value like this 'language' => 'se' then I guess the swedish option will be selected if no parameter is used in the shortcode call!?

Comment: Correct. Using `[my_shortcode]` without a language attribute will use the default of `'se'`

Comment: And also if in this case I guess: [my_shortcode language=""]